# WebApi post string with leading zero

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, jqgrid

My first Post after 2 Years. All my questions had been answered - until now.

I'm working with ASP.NET WebApi 2. I'm sending an string with leading zeroes. e.g. via jqgrid:

```
myGrid = $("#myGrid").jqGrid({
    url: 'api/Customer',
    datatype: "json",
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
    mtype: "POST",
    postData: "000951003684"
});
```

The ApiController Looks like:

```
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]string customerNumber)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerNumber))
        {
            factory.CreateDbService().GetCustomer(customerNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that "customerNumber" has the value "951003684" and not "000951003684" as expected.
In my opinion it's weird because the function expects a string not an integer value.
It seems that WebApi uses an integer formatter although the function expects an string value. Actually there is no need for using the integer formatter.

Does someone know how to access the whole string with leading zeroes?
Or in other words: How can I configure the WebApi, so that the leading zeroes are not cut?

EDIT:
Now I'm sure that WebApi uses an integer formatter because if I pass a string (e.g. "hallo World") my variable "customerNumber" is *NULL*

I already tried to send the same Request from a Firefox RESTClient-Tool. Same behaviour.

Comment: Your web service "cuts off" leading zeroes.
you might want to try to replace them with '&nbsp;' (non-breaking space) and do the reverse manipulation on your server

Comment: Use Fiddler to see what actually gets sent to the service, don't assume that WebAPI decided to treat your data as an integer. It may be that jqGrid decided to send the id as an integer when it serialized  `postData` to json.

Comment: @Crunch NULL means that the body wasn't recognized as Json, not that WebAPI thought it was an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the reason of the problem is wrong JSON serialization of the string. You use `postData: "000951003684"`. So the body of the request will be just

```json
000951003684
```

which is not corresponds to input JSON string `"000951003684"`. The only possible correct input JSON data could be integer (number). To serialize the data as string you have to add

```js
serializeGridData: function (postData) {
    return JSON.stringify(postData);
}
```

or change `postData: "000951003684"` to

```js
postData: JSON.stringify("000951003684")
```

or just use

```js
postData: "\"000951003684\""
```

In all the cases the data in the body will looks like

```json
"000951003684"
```

which can be deserialized as JSON string.

Comment: Great! Thx for this. Still quite strange that the WebApi doesnt care about the datatype "string" in the function signature and just tries to find a possible datatype...

Comment: now this is weird , 012345 is accepted but 099345 is not binding ,comes as null ! any clue ?

Comment: @sajanyamaha: I don't understand your question. What you mean with `,,012345`? What you do exactly? What code you use? Do you validated that you send string and not number in the body of HTTP request?

Comment: @Oleg this is my code method , PaymentTime([FromBody] string hostOtp) , now when 012345 is passed MVC binding works ,when 099543 is passed it comes as null !

Comment: @sajanyamaha: I described in my old answer how one can send string `"099543"` instead of the number `099543` to the Web method. Which **JavaScript code** you use? Do you validated with respect of Developer Tools of Chrome/IE which data sent your client to the server now? The data should contains quotes.